# Автоматические скобки в Vim

Tags: vim

Я хочу, чтобы когда я открываю фигурные скобки `{` в виме, то они автоматически открывались с двух сторон таким образом:

```
{
    | (курсор)
}
```

я попробовал плагин [delimitMate](https://github.com/vim-scripts/delimitMate.vim), но он работает по-другому. Подскажите как нужно настроить этот плагин или посоветуйте другие решения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я сам разобрался с проблемой. Чтоб открывать так скобки нужно прописать в vimrc:

```
inoremap {<CR>  {<CR>}<Esc>O
```

также плюсом будут и эти три строчки

```
inoremap {      {}<Left>
inoremap {{     {
inoremap {}     {}
```